# Including Domain Admin group in Security Group used for share permissions

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I have a file share set up on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server
I have a security group called "Allow file access" (not its real name!) which include a bunch of users and also "Domain Admins"

I have a single permission set up on the *share* to grant read/write access to "Allow file access" group.  And also the security settings for the *folder* grant full control to "Allow file acess"  ND Domain Admins

However, when logged on (as a Domain Admin) I get a Permission Denied error when trying to access the share.

If I explicitly add "Domain Admins" to the list of share permissions I am allowed access.

Am I not allowed to nest Domain Admins in other groups?

Comment: Have you logged out and then back in with your domain admin account after adding Domain admins to the other security group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out and back in again to get the new security token.

(FYI, I tested your exact scenario and this was the issue for me, so I'm betting same for you)

Comment: Thanks, that has done the trick - is there a KB/Technet article that explains why you need to do that?

Comment: Phil, I don't recall where the KB article is, but here's this if it helps: http://timstechnoblog.blogspot.com/2012/07/refreshing-group-membership-without.html